# Cannot install react native dependencies using expo-cli

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a new React-Native project up and running using expo. I am trying to install the react navigation dependencies. I followed the instructions in the docs, I downloaded "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.1", and "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.7.1" using NPM. Then when I run expo install react-native-reanimated, it throws the error Unexpected end of JSON input. I am using node version 14.6.0 and I have installed the expo-cli globally.

Comment: Show me your package.json, specifically the dependencies section.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean your npm cache...

In your command line run `npm clean cache`

Try to do what I said above... It should work...

Comment: https://imgur.com/yOh4KS7 I am still receiving this error when trying to install via expo. I hope I am not missing something obvious, thanks for the help, always appreciated.